# filtering a nested array with jq

Tags: json, select, jq

I've got the following JSON:

```
{
  "x": [
    { "a": 1 },
    { "a": 2 },
    { "b": 1 },
    { "b": 2 }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter it so that I get back:

```
{
  "x": [
    { "b": 1 },
    { "b": 2 }
  ]
}
```

I've tried

```
".x[] | select(.b)"
```

But, that gives me back just a list of the objects with b as so:

```
{ "b": 1 }
{ "b": 2 }
```

I want the original surrounding object as well. (The full JSON is much larger and with much deeper nesting.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your general requirements are unclear, but hopefully the following solution to the class of problems suggested by the example will provide the guidance you seek:

```
.x |= map(select(has("b")))
```

Comment: That is definitely an improvement, but it returns back [...] - I want it to return {x:[....]}.

Comment: Did you remember to include the `|`?